# Threaded / Nested Webmention replies from brid.gy

Tags: mastodon

I'm using brid.gy to poll my mastodon instance for webmentions, then receiving them from webmention.io.

The replies come back in a flat list, each entry's target property pointing to the original post.

Can I configure one or more of the services to include information about which posts are replies to other posts, i.e. to move some of them to the `children` property of their thread parents, or otherwise do that client-side?